# promises cannot read property then of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I've created a sample promise, and everything is matching up as far as I can tell all variables are declared and all brackets are closed up but I'm getting the error cannot return then of undefined. Can anyone offer an explanation to this? Thanks for all your help.

```
function mySandwich(data) {
  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (data > 5) {
      resolve(data);
    } else {
      reject('no data');
    }
  });
}

mySandwich(5)
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log('promise 1 num is' + data);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: You're not returning the promise in `mySandwich`

Comment: Ok thank you that makes sense

Answer (score 3):

You need to return `Promise` from `mySandwich`

```
function mySandwich(data) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (data > 5) {
            resolve(data);
        } else {
            reject("no data");
        }
    });
}

mySandwich(5)
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log("promise 1 num is" + data);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

```js
function mySandwich(data) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (data > 5) {
      resolve(data);
    } else {
      reject("no data");
    }
  });
}

mySandwich(5)
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log("promise 1 num is" + data);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: You could close this question as a typo

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal  I wouldnt close as a typo. Its a bit more of a logic error.  Closing as a dupe would make more sense, as its a common promise error..

Answer (score 0):

mySandwich is a function and not returning anything. As per your code

```
mySandwich(5)
 .then(function (data) {
  console.log("promise 1 num is" + data);
})
.catch(function (err) {
console.log(err);
});
```

It expects a promise returned from the function. That's why you are getting this error cannot return then of undefined.
You just need to add a return to mySandwhich.

```
function mySandwich(data) {
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (data > 5) {
        resolve(data);
    } else {
        reject("no data");
    }
  });
}
```